# Изменение цвета только у одного блока "wrap"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой вот HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="minus">-</div>
    <div class="colPrise">0</div>
    <div class="plus">+</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="minus">-</div>
    <div class="colPrise">0</div>
    <div class="plus">+</div>
</div>
```

Есть такой код jQuery:

```
$('.wrap .minus').click(function() {
    $(this, ".colPrise").css("background","red");
});
```

Мне нужно, чтобы после `click()`, изменялся цвет только у одного блока "wrap".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Менялся у colPrice?

```js
$('.wrap .minus').click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".wrap").find(".colPrise").css("background", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="minus">-</div>
  <div class="colPrise">0</div>
  <div class="plus">+</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="minus">-</div>
  <div class="colPrise">0</div>
  <div class="plus">+</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `closest` лучше чем `parents`, поскольку он не пытается найти всех родителей с этим классом.

Comment: @Qwertiy родитель, в данном случае, один. Чего он там ещё искать будет?

Comment: `parents` проходит всю цепочку родителей и фильтрует её в соответствии с селектором, а `closest` будет подниматься и проверять на соответствие - как только подходящий элемент будет найден, выше он не пойдёт.

Comment: @Qwertiy Сорян, Вы правы. :) Даже в этом случае производительность выше https://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/2

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, том вам надо сделать так:

```
$('.wrap .minus').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".colPrise").css("background","red");
});
```

В этом коде мы берем *родителя* того элемента по которому кликнули и в нём ищем *цену* и после этого меняем цвет этого элемента.

http://jsfiddle.net/rz9damge/

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не слишком точный. Если надо чтобы изменялся у всего блока - используем [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/s0d81ck5/)):

```
$(this).parent().css("background","red");
```

Если у `.colPrise` - используем [`.next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/chmvtm59/)):

```
$(this).next().css("background","red");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).next().css("background","red");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest(".wrap").find(".colPrise").css("background", "red");
```